# could not load library libgpg.so in play-games-plugin-for-unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-services, google-play-games

After updating to new version GooglePlayGamesPlugin-0.9.10 for unity, I'm facing a problem.

Logcat:

```
11-21 16:35:22.759: D/dalvikvm(1582): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.Dark.QuizRacer/lib/libgpg.so 0xa6a82f28
11-21 16:35:22.763: D/houdini(1582): [1597] Open Native Library /data/data/com.Dark.QuizRacer/lib/libgpg.so failed.
11-21 16:35:22.763: D/dalvikvm(1582): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.Dark.QuizRacer/lib/libgpg.so 0xa6a82f28
11-21 16:35:22.763: D/houdini(1582): [1597] Open Native Library /data/data/com.Dark.QuizRacer/lib/libgpg.so failed.
11-21 16:35:22.763: E/Unity(1582): Unable to find gpg
11-21 16:35:22.771: D/dalvikvm(1582): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.Dark.QuizRacer/lib/libgpg.so 0xa6a82f28
11-21 16:35:22.771: D/houdini(1582): [1597] Open Native Library /data/data/com.Dark.QuizRacer/lib/libgpg.so failed.
11-21 16:35:22.771: D/dalvikvm(1582): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.Dark.QuizRacer/lib/libgpg.so 0xa6a82f28
11-21 16:35:22.775: D/houdini(1582): [1597] Open Native Library /data/data/com.Dark.QuizRacer/lib/libgpg.so failed.
11-21 16:35:22.775: E/Unity(1582): Unable to find gpg
11-21 16:35:22.867: I/Unity(1582): DllNotFoundException: gpg
```

Is there any possible solution?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug. The current workaround ist to use static compiled libgpg. See here [at github](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/issues/280)